# Distinguishing between local data member and child-class data member in an inline constraint

Tags: system-verilog

I have a class with a `rand` data member `i`. This class (`child`) is a member of class `parent`, which also has a data member `i`. I would like to constrain the value of `i` in the child class to be the same as the value of `i` in the parent class. I want to do something like:

```
c.randomize with {i==this.i;};
```

but the `this.i` doesn't seem to refer to the `i` data member of the parent class. (Why?)

I can do this:

```
function void f;
  int dummy = i;
  c.randomize with {i==dummy;};
endfunction
```

or this:

```
function void f;
  c.randomize with {i==m.blk.p.i;}; // yuck!  
endfunction
```

but wonder if there is a better (built-in, non-hacky) way of distinguishing between the two `i`s.

**MCVE:**

```
class child;
  rand int i;
endclass

class parent;
  child c = new;
  int i=1;
  function void f;
    c.randomize with {i==this.i;};
  endfunction

endclass

module m;
  initial begin : blk
    parent p = new;
    p.f;
    $display("%p", p);
  end
endmodule
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2_8P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `{i==local::i}`. See section 18.7.1 of the 1800-2017 LRM

The reason `this.i` does not do what you expect is the combination of these two rules:

1. all class methods, including the built-in `randomize` method, have a built-in `this` argument. So `c.method(args)` is really `method(args, c)` and `this` becomes a variable local to the `method` set to the value of `c`
2. Identifiers within the `with` clause try to bind into the scope being randomized first before searching locally at the point where calling `randomize()`.

So `i` and `this.i` refer to the same class variable just as if you wrote

```
class A;
 bit i;
 function void method;
    i = 1;
    this.i = 2;
 endfunction
endclass
```

Comment: `{i == parent::i}` seems to work as well in this case.